# const double expression in C++

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

in the [English Wikipedia page on C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions), we can read that:

> Prior to C++11, the values of variables could be used in constant expressions only if the variables are declared const, have an initializer which is a constant expression, and are of **integral or enumeration** type.
>   C++11 **removes the restriction that the variables must be of integral** or enumeration type if they are defined with the constexpr keyword:

```
 constexpr double earth_gravitational_acceleration = 9.8;
 constexpr double moon_gravitational_acceleration = earth_gravitational_acceleration / 6.0;
```

What does it mean? In particular, does it mean that:

```
const double earth_gravitational_acceleration = 9.8;
const double moon_gravitational_acceleration = earth_gravitational_acceleration / 6.0;
```

is illegal in C++ prior to C++11? g++ is totally OK with this, even with `-ansi`, `-pedantic` and other...

Thanks!

Comment: The expressions in your second example are not [*constant expressions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

Comment: The difference between *compile-time* and *runtime* constants is the key issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see a difference, you need to start by using the result in some way that requires a constant expression, such as defining the size of an array. Since g++ has an extension that allows C99-style variable length arrays in C++, you probably need to make those globals as well.

So, let's consider a few possibilities:

```
double a = 12.34;              // non-const
const double b = a;            // const initialized from non-const. Allowed
const double b_prime = 12.34;  // const initialized from literal.
double constexpr c = 34.56;    // constexpr instead. 

int x[(int)a];                 // fails. `a` is not a constant expression
int y[(int)b];                 // fails. `b` is `const`, but not a constant expression
int y_prime[(int) b_prime];    // works in g++, but shouldn't be allowed.
int z[(int)c];                 // works
```

Note that `constexpr` is new enough that some compilers don't support it (e.g., VC++ doesn't, at least up through the version included in VS 2013).

Comment: Thank you @jerry-coffin! In fact, what I can not understand in the Wikipedia article, is what was allowed with "const int" variables that was not authorized with "const double" variables in C++ before the appearance of "constexpr" for "double" variables?

Comment: @Greg82: I kind of messed up in the original post. At least as I read things, the definition of `y_prime` should not actually be allowed (even though g++ allows it). As of C++11, `z` (which is essentially similar, but with `constexpr` added) is allowed.

Comment: Should numerical double values not have an L at the end to distintuish them from floats, i.e. like 12.34L or 34.56L ?

Comment: @smoe: floating point literals are double by default. An "f" or "F" suffix gives a `float`.

Answer (score 5):

Your second example is not at all illegal. It's just *not a compile-time constant*. The values may possibly be computed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

They provided an example on the same page:

```
int get_five() {return 5;}

int some_value[get_five() + 7]; // Create an array of 12 integers. Ill-formed C++03

constexpr int get_five() {return 5;}

int some_value[get_five() + 7]; // Create an array of 12 integers. Legal C++11
```

Because `get_five` is guaranteed to be 5 at compile-time, it can be used in a constant expression.

For example this will cause an error:

```
constexpr int get_five() { int a = 5; return a;}
```

Comment: I think they want to relax the specification to allow the example in your second code section `constexpr int get_five() { int a = 5; return a; }`. The result is actually compile-time constant. The current specification is just a concession to the limited capabilities of the current compilers to detect this case. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html